# Why concatenate install arguments in a docker file?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

One of our projects has a `Dockerfile` with code like this:

```
RUN apt-get install -y PACKAGE1 PACKAGE2 PACKAGE3 etc
```

This is equivalent to:

```
RUN apt-get install -y PACKAGE1
RUN apt-get install -y PACKAGE2
RUN apt-get install -y PACKAGE3
etc
```

The latter method uses more characters, but it is more explicit and (at least for me) easier to scan and visually debug. For example, you can find duplicate packages or add a comment about why a particular package is required.

Are there technical advantages to cramming everything on one line like this?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the second approach , you will end with a large Docker image since every run command will crate a new layer in your image.

in the other hand the first command will create only one more layer for the image.

see [this](https://hackernoon.com/tips-to-reduce-docker-image-sizes-876095da3b34) and [this](https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612)

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks. Guess I need to understand what this "layer" thing means...sounds like a `snapshot` of a virtual machine.

Comment: see also this : https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612

Answer (score -1):

The advantage of the second approach is that built image layers are reused if you rebuild the image. Each layer corresponds to Dockerfile data manipulation instruction. Docker caches the built layers that hasn't changed and rebuilds only layer that changed and layers that come after according to Dockerfile instructions. So data manipulation instructions should be ordered according to variability of the data being manipulated. For example, *Dockerfile* instructions like source code copying should be last.